# Why does div change size when I add a border

Tags: html, css

There's not much to explain, just take a look.

**Div No Border:**

```css
p {
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>p text</p>
</div>
```

Output:

[image: Div No Border Output]

**Div Border:**

```css
p {
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>p text</p>
</div>
```

Output:
[image: Div No Border]

Why does the red div increase its height when a border is added to it?

Comment: you should look up the CSS property `box-sizing`. By default it it is set to `content-box` which means the height is calculated to the height of the content. That does not include padding and border. The next thing is, by adding a border the default margin of the paragraph will be visible as it can't collapse anymore.

Comment: Worth a watch too: https://youtu.be/qKiz9gdJdr8

Comment: Just add a CSS reset, something like this: `* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }`, add it to every CSS code from now on.